# How does $wpdb->get_var work with offset?

Tags: wpdb

In WordPress documentation, it says:

(https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

> SELECT a Variable The get_var function returns a single variable from
>   the database. Though only one variable is returned, the entire result
>   of the query is cached for later use. Returns NULL if no result is
>   found.
>
> get_var( 'query', column_offset, row_offset ); ?>
>
> query  (string) The query you wish to run. Setting this parameter to
>   null will return the specified variable from the cached results of the
>   previous query. 
>   column_offset  (integer) The desired column (0 being
>   the first). Defaults to 0. 
>   row_offset  (integer) The desired row (0
>   being the first). Defaults to 0.

My query is, can you please explain this line:

> Setting this parameter to
>   null will return the specified variable from the cached results of the
>   previous query.

Which variable? If i code:

```
<?php $wpdb->get_var( null, column_offset, row_offset ); ?>
```

Which variables value is it talking about?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [improve your question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). Summarize your specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify values for column_offset and row_offset. For example:

```
 <?php $wpdb->get_var( null, 5, 0 ); ?>
```

Will return "Hello World" (see attached image) But for that to work you had to have a previous query like this:

```
 <?php $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts" ); ?>
```

[image: result set from previous query]